# Delete file at specified time non-interactively

Tags: at

I have a script that when executed generates a temp file that i want deleted 10 minutes after the script completes.

I have looked at the "at" command which does what I need, but it requires interactive input. Is there any way to do this non-interactively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man at`:

> **at** and **batch** read commands from standard input or a specified file which are to be executed at a later time, using **/bin/sh**.

So just send the command you would type in interactively to `at` as input:

```
echo 'rm that.file' | at now+10min
```

Comment: that will work, don't know why I didn't think of piping to at.

Comment: I just remembered a similar problem I had with ftp some years ago which had a solution I could reuse, this also seems to work:

`at now + 10 min <<'EOF'
rm $file
EOF`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is using the command *sleep*.
For example 'sleep 600 && rm that.file' will delete that.file after 600 seconds ('man sleep' shows a more detailed example).